# Define an instance variable by the presence of a character in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

With Ruby, how can I define an instance variable by the presence of a character in a string?

I've been trying to use `includes` but that's apparently not a built-in method.

```
def reply 
  @reply = @tweet.includes("@") 
end
```

Also, how can I ensure that the "@" refers to an actual user and isn't just floating in the tweet or prefixed to an invalid username? If `includes` worked, I was going to try:

```
def valid_reply 
  @valid_reply = @tweet.includes("@" + @username) 
end
```

Comment: Why is the only role of those methods to set an instance variable?

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right, the method you are looking for is called [`include?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/include%3F):

```
def valid_reply 
  @valid_reply = @tweet.include?("@" + @username)
end
```

After this, `@valid_reply` will be either `true` or `false`, depending on whether `@tweet` contains the substring `@[username]`.

**NOTE:** The fact that this method only sets an instance variable to a boolean value sounds a bit suspicious. If I had to code this, I'd probably define a method `valid_reply?` that checks whether the @tweet is a valid reply:

```
def valid_reply?
  @tweet.include?("@#{@username}")
end
```

You also see the use of expression substitution here (although it looks quite strange in this case).